# Remove Nth node from end of the list

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I was trying to understand from the following code why head is getting returned. I suppose it returns null. Could someone explain me about it ?

```
public ListNode removeNthFromEnd(ListNode head, int n) {
    if(head == null)
        return null;

    ListNode fast = head;
    ListNode slow = head;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        fast = fast.next;
    }

    //if remove the first node
    if(fast == null){
        head = head.next;
        return head;
    }

    while(fast.next != null){
        fast = fast.next;
        slow = slow.next;
    }

    slow.next = slow.next.next;

    return head;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: *why head is getting returned* -- That is all you do... `return head` twice. You should check your if statements. Plus, I'm concerned why `fast = fast.next` isn't throwing a nullpointerexception. Are you guaranteed `n` is less than the length of the list?

Comment: How is this method supposed to work?  If I give it a list of A, B, C, D, E, and an `n` of 2, is the final list supposed to be A, B, C, E or A, B, C?

Comment: In case of linked list head will always be returned since it is the starting point of the list(we start with head to iterate through the list), if head is null the list is empty. If you remove the nth node in a non empty list where n>1 the head is unchanged and it is again natural to start with head to print the list.

Comment: Given linked list: 1->2->3->4->5, and n = 2.
After removing the second node from the end, the linked list becomes 1->2->3->5. So how is it possible to return the above linked list by returning the head

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better way of removing the nth element from the end of the list. You can use a stack. Put the elements in the stack till you reach the end. Then, start popping till the nth element from the end. Then, the next of the popped element (nth) is the next. Also, the previous of the nth element in the stack peek. All you need to do it to set the next of prev as the next. You need to consider removing the head and tail of the list as edge cases. Also, you need to consider the empty list. I hope it helps.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class RemoveNthNodeFromLL {

    public static class ListNode {
        int val;
        ListNode next;

        ListNode() {
        }

        ListNode(int val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

        ListNode(int val, ListNode next) {
            this.val = val;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    public ListNode removeNthFromEnd(ListNode head, int n) {
        if (head == null || (head.next == null)) return null;
        Stack<ListNode> s = new Stack<>();
        ListNode prev = null;
        ListNode curr = head;
        while (curr != null) {
            prev = curr;
            s.push(prev);
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++) {
            s.pop();
        }
        ListNode toBeRemoved = s.pop();
        ListNode next = toBeRemoved.next;
        if (s.isEmpty()) {
            // Removing the head
            head = head.next;
        } else {
            prev = s.peek();
            prev.next = next;
        }
        return head;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RemoveNthNodeFromLL r = new RemoveNthNodeFromLL();
        ListNode head = new ListNode(1, new ListNode(2, new ListNode(3, new ListNode(4, new ListNode(5)))));
        System.out.println(r.removeNthFromEnd(head, 2));
    }

}
```